# DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, datagridviewcolumn

I am using a *DataGridView* to display some data in my application.
The data in the table gets changed dynamically according to the users input.
I am able to retrieve the data according to the user.

I have to add an extra column named `ID` and fill in the values serially starting from 1 to the number of rows which are generated dynamically.

I had added the column `using dgrid.columns.add("UID");`

But how to insert values at runtime?

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your code, it is not correct to do:

```
dgrid.Columns.Add("UID");
```

You will have to do:

```
dgrid.Columns.Add("uidColumn", "UID");
```

To modify/add the value of an existing cell, if the row already exists, you can do:

```
dgrid.Rows[0].Cells["uidColumn"].Value = myValue;
```

That will modify the value of the column with name `uidColumn` and row  `0`. According to your problem, all you have to do is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgrid.Rows.Count; i++) {
    dgrid.Rows[i].Cells["uidColumn"].Value = GetValueOfRow(i);
}
```

supposing that you have a method `GetValueOfRow` that receives a row index and returns the value you need in the `ID` column in that row.